# Magento 2.1 - Sitemap XML Doesn't change to HTTPS

Tags: magento-2.1, sitemaps, secure

```
Use Secure URLs on Storefront = Yes

Use Secure URLs in Admin = Yes

Secure Base URL = starts with HTTPS
```

Why does my sitemap not start each link with https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8644 shows this issue to have been fixed in versions 2.1.9 and 2.2.0. The workaround below appears to work if you're unable to update your store.

Update the **Base URL** of the store you are generating the sitemap for.

From the admin dashboard:

1. Go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**
2. Expand **General** and select **Web**
3. *If you have multiple stores, confirm you are updating the correct store by referencing the scope switcher at the top left of the page.*
4. Expand **Base URLs**
5. Update the protocol used in **Base URL** from `http://` to `https://`
6. Click **Save Config** and clear cache
7. Generate the sitemap and confirm URL's have been updated.

[image]